# error when trying to enter values in database php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I tried to insert into a mySQL database using PHP. I am using XAMPP server, and the way to the project i am working on is in htdocs/proiect

the php code is

```
if($ok == 0){
        $hostname = "localhost";
        $database = "Forum";
        $db_table = "Users";
        $db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','');
        mysql_select_db($database,$db);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $db_table(name,email) values (nvl(select max(user_id) from Users,0)+1,'".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['userTxt']))."','".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['passTxt'])) ."','".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['emailTxt']))."',sysdate,'A')";
        if($result = mysql_query($sql ,$db)) {
            echo '<h1>Thank you</h1>Your information has been entered into our database<br><br>';
        } else {
            echo "ERROR: ".mysql_error();
        }
    }
```

the error I get is

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'select max(user_id) from Users,0)+1,'cdscs','as','csdcsd',sysdate,'A')' at line 1
```

the table is

[image: hei]

Comment: don't use `mysql_` functions they are deprecated

Comment: There's an error in your SQL syntax, so the first thing you should do is look at the actual SQL code you're trying to execute.  What is the runtime value of `$sql`?  Note that, given your SQL injection vulnerability, you're not actually controlling the code that you execute.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Comment: Also, what on Earth is that first value you're trying to insert?  And why are you trying to insert 4 values into 2 columns?

Comment: Practice Practice...

Comment: `values (nvl` wha'dat?

Comment: I corrected the code regarding the two columns, but still no successful result. I am trying to insert the primary key, and for the first value inserted, assuming the select returns null, I used nvl to convert it to 0. I am not used to mySQL, I've worked so far in sqlDeveloper

Comment: @IleanaProfeanu: If you're still getting errors then clearly you haven't corrected the code.  We can't tell you what the problem is if you don't show us the code that's being executed.  As for that primary key column, use an `AUTOINCREMENT` instead.  Manually determining the "next integer" is a recipe for errors.

Comment: it worked, thank you so much guys!!!